# How to add data in a Listbox of Tkinter from another Class?

Tags: python, user-interface, listbox, tkinter

I have a GUI class with a (button , two entry boxes and a Listbox), I want to insert in Listbox some data from another class. Here is my GUI class...

```
class GUI(object):      
def __init__(self, parent):
    frame = Frame(parent.title("CAN Interface"))
    frame.pack()
    self.lbfirst = Label(frame, text="CAN ID:")
    self.lbfirst.grid(row=1,column=0)
    self.first = Entry(frame)
    self.first.grid(row=2,column=0)
    self.lbsecond = Label(frame, text="CAN Data:")
    self.lbsecond.grid(row=1,column=2)
    self.second = Entry(frame)
    self.second.grid(row=2,column=2)
    self.number=Button(frame, text="Send", fg="red", command=self.call_comm)
    self.number.grid(row=5,column=1)
    self.result = Listbox(frame)
    self.result.grid(row=9,column=0, columnspan=5, sticky=N+S+E+W)

def call_comm_rxc(self, data1):
    print("in call_comm_rxc")
    self.data1 = data1
    self.result.insert (END, 'CAN ID : '+str(self.data1[0])+'|Length : '+str(self.data1[1])+'|Data : '+str(self.data1[2]))
```

& this is my other class from which I want to access **self.result** attribute of GUI class

```
class Comm(Thread, Format, GUI):
def __init__(self):
    Thread.__init__(self) # Call the Thread class's init function
def run(self):
    while True:
        # here need to add the code which needs to run all the time
        print("in true")            
        self.CAN_Receive()

def CAN_Receive(self):
    print("in rxc")
    #self.result1 = result1
    self.data = Format.UnPack(self,b'\x12\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
    GUI.call_comm_rxc(self, self.data)
```

The error which i am facing is "AttributeError: 'Comm' object has no attribute 'result'

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python33\lib\threading.py", line 901, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "E:\Studies\Ctech\MicroLab Files\example code.py", line 124, in run
self.CAN_Receive()
File "E:\Studies\Ctech\MicroLab Files\example code.py", line 141, in CAN_Receive
GUI.call_comm_rxc(self, self.data)
File "E:\Studies\Ctech\MicroLab Files\example code.py", line 110, in call_comm_rxc
self.result.insert (END, 'CAN ID : '+str(self.data1[0])+'|Length : '+str(self.data1[1])+'|Data :   '+str(self.data1[2]))
AttributeError: 'Comm' object has no attribute 'result'
```

Kindly help me how can i insert in a Listbox from child class (Comm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization of class `GUI` is missing in class `Comm`.

Add `GUI.__init__(self, parent)` into the `Comm.__init__`.

Comment: Yes this point was missing but how can i pass parent attribute to `Comm.__init__(self, parent)` which will be passed to `GUI.__init__(self, parent)`. I have the code `testComm = Comm()`
`testComm.start()`

`root = Tk()`
`app = GUI(root)`
`root.mainloop()`

Comment: @user3159610 Put `root = Tk()` at the beginning and make `testComm = Comm(root)`